# How do i detect Key release C++

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

So i am making a software to help me with an arduino project, it is supossed to be like PUTTY. I programed the arduino to play different notes from Q-I(C4-C5) and the software is supossed to play thoes notes but i need to make it detect when the Key is pressed and released, how do i do that? I searched and found something but it is not working like it's supposed to here is the code:

```
int main(){
int KeyGet;

while(1)
    {
    KeyGet = getch();
    if (GetKeyState(0x51) & 0x8000)
    {
        cout<<"key is pressed"<< endl;
    }
    else if(GetKeyState(0x51)& 0x0001)
    {

        cout<<"key is released"<< endl;
    }


    }


return 0;
```

The program just prints "key is pressed" when i press Q(0x51) and not "key released" as it should, insted it prints "key released" when i press something else other the Q. And i tried `GetAsyncKeyState` and tried

```
If (GetKeyState(0x51) != 0)
```

it still doesent work.

Comment: You can try just printing `GetKeyState(0x51)` in hexadecimal with use of `std::hex`. And try to press the key. Note what changes in different moments

Comment: I dont need it to print what number it is (already did that it works) i need to know when it is released. Yes im using windows and i included all the headers.

Comment: Don't use GetKeyState in console programs.

Answer (score 1):

`GetKeyState()` requires a window and a message loop to keep the state machine updated. But you do not have a message loop.  Also, `getch()` would swallow any key press+release anyway.

Also, `GetKeyState(0x51) & 0x0001` is not the right way to detect a key release. That bit is meant for detecting the toggle state of togglable keys like <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, etc.

In your example, you would need to get rid of `getch()` and use `GetAsyncKeyState()` instead, eg:

```
int main(){
    bool down = false;
    while (1) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x51) < 0) {
            if (!down) {
                down = true;
                cout << "key is pressed" << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (down) {
                down = false;
                cout << "key is released"<< endl;
            }
        }
        Sleep(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use a `WH_KEYBOARD[_LL]` hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` instead, so you can receive actual key down/up notifications in real-time.